# assign children pid's created in a loop to an array

Tags: c, fork

(Edited: fixed some stuff based on your comments but still not results i need- some procesess get orphaned and get parent init(pid 1), is it because termination loop is inside the other loop? how else could i activate and terminate on the same loop that i forked? )

In the following code, I need to print the pid's created with `fork()` in the loop in a message when a signal is sent to the process but I get the default value for all pid's (0). The homework involved sending signals to the child processes according to the arguments series ie `./a.out 1 3 5 4 2` will have to send signals to child processes  `1 3 5 4 2` in that order and print their pid in that order also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

/*SIGCHLD, SIGCONT*/
int status;
static int alarmOn = 0;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    

 pid_t pid[5], f;
     void activateChild(int signal)
        {
             alarmOn = 1;
        }
     (void) signal(SIGCONT,activateChild);


     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)         
 { 
   f = fork();
       if (f < 0 )
            {   

        printf("\nfork failed\n");

    }
   if (f == 0)
    {   

        printf("\nprocess %d, %d is paused\n",i,getpid());
                pause();    
    }

    if (f > 0)
        {   


                    pid[i]=f;
                        kill(pid[atoi(argv[i])],SIGCONT);
                        if(alarmOn)
                            {
                            printf("\nchild %s  pid: %d is executed %d\n ",argv[i+1],pid[atoi(argv[i+1])],i);
                                sleep(3);
                            }

                    kill(pid[atoi(argv[i+1])],SIGCHLD);



        }


      }
       exit(0);


return(0);
}
```

Comment: use `atoi(argv[j])` to convert a parameter string to a number.

Comment: and you probably shouldn't hardcode for 5 arguments, but utilize argc.

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Please copy paste the exact code you are using.

Comment: @RingØ This is one of the rare posts, which indeed are close to an MCVE. Just because a single character got lost doesn't negate that. +1 from me. (just the indention could be improved ;)

Comment: The killing loop needs to be after the launching loop, not part of it.

Comment: Also note that SIGCONT doesn't continue a process waiting in `pause()`; it continues a process hung by SIGSTOP (and maybe a few other signals).  It is unconventional to send SIGCHLD to a child process, too.  You should think about using SIGTERM or SIGHUP.  You should probably wait for the children and capture their exit status.  There's no clear reason that `status` needs to be a global variable — AFAICS, it is unused.

Comment: @Ctx The fact that a `]` is missing suggests that OP wrote manually the code in SO, instead of doing a copy-paste ; thus the code might have other added mistakes less obvious than a missing character, like a line missing.

Comment: Remember array indexing in C is zero based.  When you declare `pid_t pid[5]`, you are allowed to access `pid[0]` through `pid[4]`, but instead you access `pid[1]` through `pid[5]`, and the last of these is out of bounds.

Comment: @RingØ I would agree if the mistakes weren't obvious here.